# A process receiving infinite standard input never exits when called from a systemd service

Tags: linux, bash, services, systemd

I'm writing a simple systemd service that writes the output of `vmstat` over a websocket in order to do some CPU utilization testing of another application. I'm piping the output of `vmstat` to `wscat` like this:

```
vmstat -n 1 | wscat localhost:1234
```

`vmstat -n 1` outputs a status line every second to stdout.

Everything works just fine as long as my web socket server is already listening when the stat service starts. But if the server isn't listening, I want my `stat-test` service to fail and then automatically retry every 10 seconds.

However, when I run this as a service, `wscat` doesn't ever exit (even though it fails) so my service doesn't ever restart. At first I thought there was something wrong with `wscat`, but it still hangs even if I pipe the output of `vmstat` to `nonfunction` instead.

For simplicity, I'm only posting this minimal failing test case.

`stat-test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

vmstat -n 1 | nonfunction
echo Exited with $?
```

`stat-test.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stat-Test

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/stat-test.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=10000ms

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `./stat-test.sh` directly from the terminal, I get:

```
stat-test.sh: line 3: nonfunction: command not found
Exited with 127
```

However, when I run it as a service with `systemctl start stat-test`, I get:

```
systemd[1]: Started Stat-Test.
bash[32168]: /path/stat-test.sh: line 3: nonfunction: command not found
```

Notice it never prints out the exit code. For some reason, the failing command never exits and moves on when run as a service.

However, if I change it to: `echo 1 | nonfunction`, the service fails properly. So, it looks like the fact that `vmstat` runs forever is somehow causing the command it is piped to to never exit, but only when running as a service.

Why is this happening, and how can I get my service to fail properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [similar problem on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44358723/10765659). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44376786/10765659):

> Set `IgnoreSIGPIPE=false` under `[Service]` in the `.service` file. From the `systemd.exec` manual:
>
> > ```
> > IgnoreSIGPIPE=
> >    Takes a boolean argument. If true, causes
> >    SIGPIPE to be ignored in the executed process.
> >    Defaults to true because SIGPIPE generally is
> >    useful only in shell pipelines.
> > ```

Read the whole answer there for explanation. In your case `vmstat` ignores `SIGPIPE` and you don't want it to.

After you apply the solution, remove `echo` from your script because it will affect the exit status.